# Test class for Batch

Tags: unit-test

hi guyz im new in salesforce can anyone help meh with my code for testclass 
heres the code:

```
@isTest
public class Testclass {

    @isTest static void Testclass() {

        List<sobject> lmsin = [Select Id,Name,Field1,Field1,Field1,(Select Id, Field1 from sobject) from sobject];
        insert lmsin;
        sobject lmsca = new sobject();
        lmsca.Name = '';
        lmsca.Field1 = '';
        lmsca.Field1 = '';
        lmsca.Field1 = '';
        insert lmsca;


        test.startTest();

        Batchclass lcfb = new Batchclass();
        Database.executeBatch(lcfb,1);

        test.stopTest();        
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the issue with code?

Comment: I don’t think you can reference fields like that for a generic sObject. Also what does your start method look like. What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will approach this by setting up your test data and then running the test:

```
@isTest
private class BatchTestClass{

    @testSetup static void setupData()
    {

        // Inserting test data here 


       // Do some asserts here to make sure your data is corret
        System.assertEquals(); 
        System.assertEquals(); 
        System.assertEquals(); 

    }
    // Run your test
    @isTest static void Runtest() 
    {   
        // Firing apex bacth class      
        Test.startTest();
        YourBatchClassName batchToTest = new YourBatchClassName (); 
        Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(batchToTest );
        Test.stopTest();

        // After batch is completed run asserts here 
        System.assertEquals();
        System.assertEquals();
        System.assertEquals();



    }

}
```

So you need to insert the test data that will be similar to the expecting data from your batch operation. Then run a test calling the real batch class name. 
Make sure you assert your test data an expecting results.